# An assertion about series convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was wondering whether the following assertion is true.

Given the series $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {a_i\frac{i}{n}}$ with  $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}|a_i|<\infty$
Is that enough to guarantee that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} {a_i\frac{i}{n}}=0$?

I was trying to prove it but didn't get anywhere. I am starting to think that the assertion is in fact false. Does anyone know a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is true. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, by the assumed absolute convergence there is an $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sum_{i = m+1}^{\infty} \lvert a_i\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\,.$$

Then for such a fixed $m$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^m \lvert a_i\rvert\cdot i < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

for all $n \geqslant N$. For $n > \max \{m, N\}$ we therefore have

\begin{align}
\Biggl\lvert \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} a_i\frac{i}{n}\Biggr\rvert &\leqslant \Biggl\lvert \sum_{i = 1}^m a_i \frac{i}{n}\Biggr\rvert + \Biggl\lvert \sum_{i = m+1}^{n-1} a_i \frac{i}{n}\Biggr\rvert \\
&\leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^m \lvert a_i\rvert \frac{i}{n} + \sum_{i = m+1}^{n-1} \lvert a_i\rvert \frac{i}{n} \\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^m i\lvert a_i\rvert + \sum_{i = m+1}^{n-1} \lvert a_i\rvert \\
&< \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: In the last equality aren't you missing the $i$?,$\sum_{i=m+1}^{n-1}|a_i|i$

Comment: In the last sum I use $\frac{i}{n} < 1$ for the estimate.